# Simple "maximum value in array" and complexity calculations

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm pretty new to this stuff and I need your help.

I should build an efficient simple algorithm which returns the maximum value in an array with size of n which contains the numbers 1,2,...n with repetitions.

Then I have to determine the best running time, average running time and worst running time.

So I have two questions:

1. First of all I'm trying to understand what's the idea of requiring an efficient solution for  this simple algorithm. As far as I understand I should only have a simple loop from 1 to n and look for the maximum value. Is the "efficient" algorithm points out that If I find the value n in the array I can stop searching more values because this is the maximum value in the array?
2. How do I determine the best running time and average running time using the fact, while calculating the average running time, that It's a uniform distribution.
   That is, each cell in the array has a chance of 1/n to be the maximum value.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Sounds like homework... what have you come up with so far? Hint: sorted arrays have O(1) runtime for max/min values.

Comment: @MarcB: But determining the array is sorted is O(n) :|

Comment: so's simply pulling out the max/min values on any arbitrary array.

Comment: @MarcB the array isn't sorted. I'm not requiring a solution but some  explanation for concrete answer. As for what I came up so far, I wrote in my question.

Comment: probably with #1 is that you CAN'T know what the max/min values in the array are until you've scanned the entire array, or know in advance that the array is pre-sorted. e.g. for arbitrary "don't know if sorted arrays", it's an O(n) operation to get that max/min value set.

Comment: Yeah, of course It's O(n). but the fact there are only numbers between 1..n allows me to make the algorithm a little bit more efficient by stop searching in case I found the value n. right?

Comment: "The maximum value in an array with size of n which contains the numbers 1,2,...n with repetitions" is obviously n, isn't it?

Comment: It contains numbers between 1...n (not all of them). Also the fact there might be repetitions implies not all the numbers always show.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Best case - finding the max element as the first (`O(1)`), worst case - it is the last element checked (`O(n)`).

The tricky part is the average case.

To find the average case - we need the [expected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) number of iterations!

Since you can stop after you find the maximum, we can split the problem into two parts:

1. `[0,n-1)`: Since on average (assuming uniform independent distribution for each element) - the number `n` has probability 1/n to be in each place, then the expected number of iterations for this part is `1/n + 2*((n-1)/n)/n + 3 * ((n-1)/n)^2/n + ... + (n-1) * ((n-1)/n)^(n-2)/n` <sup>1</sup>

   [The above formula yields an ugly formula which is `O(n)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20j*%28%28n-1%29/n%29%5E%28j-1%29%20*%20%281/n%29%20j%20from%201%20to%20n-1%20)
2. The last element is going to be checked if the first n-1 elements did not contain the value `n`: so you need to add to the above `n* ((n-1)/n)^(n-1)`, which is `O(n)` as well (lim to infinity is `1/e * n`).

**This totals in `O(n)` average time solution.**

---

(1): The formula for each element is `j*((n-1)/n)^(j-1) * (1/n)` because:

- `j` - for the number of elements checked (number of iterations)
- `((n-1)/n)^(j-1)` - Probability that there is no `n` in the previous elements
- `(1/n)` - Probability this number is `n`.

Comment: Wow @amit I have no words. So nicely put. Really appreciating this.

Comment: The "with duplicates" bit says that it is not a random permutation.  Merely n random integers in the range `1..n`.

Comment: @btilly: The term permutation was wrong, but note that the caclulation did not assume permutation - it assumed uniform distribution for each element - so it (each element) has `1/n` chance to be the max, and `(n-1)/n` not to be it. I'll correct the terminology. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Why is the best case O(1)? You can't be certain that any one element of an array is the max without knowing what's in the rest of the array...

Comment: @William Note that the question states that the array `contains the numbers 1,2,...n with repetitions`. The best case is actually: read the first element, see it's n, and return it. This is O(1).

Comment: @BarzanHayati I explained the rationale here, do you think anything is flawed with it? Please point at what's not correct in your opinion, and I'll try to see if it is indeed wrong - or if I can explain it better.

Answer (score 4):

If there is no prior information about the array (e.g. it's sorted), then there is no worst case or best case, and You have to scan all the elements to find out the Max, and it takes O(n) times.

Also, knowing the probability distribution of getting max value for each cell is useless in general (unless it reduces your search space. e.g., If you know that only constant number of cells have non-zero probability of getting the max value, then you just need to search those cells and it takes constant time). Thus, in general

Best-case running time = Worst-case running time = average running time = O(n)

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm works like this, first you select a number (in this case i select the first number of the array and pretend it is the max, then i compare it to the next number and if it is larger I take that as the new max, until i finish searching in the array), the next code is in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100

typedef struct{
    int val;
    int loc;
} find;

/* Functions declaration (Prototype) */
find maxFinder( int * const a );

int main( void )
{
    int response[ SIZE ]=
       { 1, 3, 5, 7,  8, 9, 0, 10, 65, 100,
         1, 3, 5, 7,  8, 9, 0, 10, 65, 100,
         1, 3, 5, 7,  8, 9, 0, 10, 65, 100,
         1, 3, 5, 7,  8, 9, 0, 10, 65, 100,
         1, 3, 5, 7,  8, 9, 0, 10, 65, 100,
         1, 3, 5, 7,  8, 9, 0, 10, 65, 100,
         1, 3, 5, 7,  8, 9, 0, 10, 65, 100,
         1, 3, 5, 7,  8, 9, 0, 10, 65, 100,
         1, 3, 5, 7,  8, 9, 0, 10, 65, 100,
         1, 3, 5, 7,  8, 9, 0, 10, 65, 100 };

    printf( "The max number is %d located in the index %d.\n", maxFinder( response ).val, maxFinder( response ).loc );
    return 0;
}

 find maxFinder( int * const a )
 {
    /* Local Variables initialization & declaration */
    int i;
    find result;

    result.loc = 0;
    result.val = *( a + 0 );

    for( i = 1; i < SIZE; i++ ){
        if ( result.val < *( a + i ) ){
            result.loc = i;
            result.val = *( a + i );
        }
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use the fact the numbers are between 1... SIZE?

Comment: SIZE is a constant value that you must declare, in my case it's 100.

Comment: In this case SIZE = n and your values are between 1...n. This is not a general case as you have shown.

Comment: It is general case, just change SIZE value as you wish, and it searchs from 0 (first element of the array until the array finishes (n-1)

Comment: @Alberto Bonsanto: Can you share the code in Javascript / PHP! please

Answer (score 1):

The worst and best cases are simple.  The average case is more interesting.  Look at the Wikipedia page for [Geometric Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Comment: Best case - in case it is the first element : O(1) and worst case : O(n) , is that right?

Comment: Based on your comments you seem like you are confident and you understand the idea.  Go with your instincts :)

Answer (score 0):

**What if we traverse only half of the length of the array?
Will it become O(n/2) time complexity?**

```
array = [6, 8, 9, 4, 100]

l = len(array)
max = 0

for i in range(l//2):
  if max<array[i]:
    max = array[i]
  
  if max<array[-1-i]:
    max = array[-1-i]

if l%2!=0:
  if max<array[i+1]:
    max = array[i+1]

print(max)
```

Here Im traversing array from the both side at a time - Is it a faster solution to find max value in array or we have any better way?