# How to find the largest length for every column in a huge multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

We have this type of array and max represents the length of the word in the columns.

```
var data = [
   ["1111", "44"],
   ["222", "55555"  ],
   ["33", "666"  ],
...
];

"1111".length > "222".length > "33".length,
"55555".length > "666".length > "44".length
var max -> [4,5];
```

Because this array is really huge, what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159594/simple-maximum-value-in-array-and-complexity-calculations

Comment: You could try keeping the array sorted by word length whenever you insert new values. Then you'll only need to find the first/last value in the array. (depending on how it's sorted)

Comment: I don't think I get you

Comment: JGrice makes a great comment regarding keeping sorted arrays, otherwise you are going to have to eat the whole meal.

Comment: you cannot sort the arrays, because they represent in what order the values will be show. I need this, so I could somehow calculate the width of the column and create a table, because I will be using virtual scrolling.

Comment: this is not the same question as of Cerbrus.

Comment: Isn't it? You are going to have to eat the entire data structure (as stated you can't presort) so there is no algorithm efficiency to be had other than choosing the least costly comparison method. The linked SO question has a nice set of JSPerf tests with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
   ['ABC', 'ABCD', 'ABCDEF', 'abcd', 'a', 'Abcdef', 'Abcderfg', 'A', 'ABC'],
   ['ABCD', 'ABC', 'ABCDEF', 'abc', 'AB', 'Abcdef', 'abcd', 'ABC', 'ABC'],
   ['Abcderfg', 'ABC', 'ABCDEFGH', 'abc', 'A', 'ABCDEF', 'abcd', 'AB', 'ABC']
];


var _maxs = [];  
var lenghtOfRow = data[0].length, _maxs = [];
for (var i=0; i<lenghtOfRow; i++) 
    _maxs.push(0);


data.forEach(function (record) {
   record.forEach(function (vl, indx) {
     if (vl.length > _maxs[indx])
         _maxs[indx] = vl.length;
   })
});

console.log(_maxs);
```

Is there a more effective way?

Updated:

```
_maxs = [];

data.forEach(function (record) {
   record.forEach(function (vl, indx) {
      if (vl.length > (_maxs[indx]|| 0))
          _maxs[indx] = vl.length;
    })
});
```

Comment: yes, and it is not correct.

my maxs: [8, 4, 8, 4, 2, 6, 8, 3, 3]
your maxs: [8, 2: 6, 6: 8]

Comment: My answer outputs `[4,5]` using the data in question. Where does `[8, 2: 6, 6: 8]` come from?

Comment: @MatjažJurečič You can skip your first loop pushing zeroes by doing in the inner forEach: `if (vl.length > (_maxs[indx] || 0)) ...`

Comment: from your answer, if I used different data. The question is not only for this data, but for different data also.

Comment: @MatjažJurečič: ok, glad you figured it out.